# Git branches on different environments

Tags: git, version-control, branch, development-environment, git-flow

I am new to git and i am trying to set a git flow on different environments.
I have a production environment that has the central repos with post receive hooks with the master branch a development branch for development server and a test environment with the release branches for the test environment.My idea and i don't know if it's correct is for the people to work on development environment make test on test and then push to the master branch(production).

My question is how do you work with different branches on different environments?
You have clone repos on development with development branch running and a clone of the central repo on the test environment for the release or test branch and after the developers do the changes we go to these environments and do git pull --all?

What is the best practice?I know each developer makes a clone repo.Makes the changes and then pushes the changes.But in our case how do they see them working at first glance? They are suppose to do the changes see if they work at first glance and then commit the changes.This happens to development environment which it has a dev environment set up(databases etc) which is not possible for the devs to have.But if we have a clone repo on dev the repo cannot be shared.

Or for every small change they have to clone push their local and then go in de v environment do a pull to see their changes and how the system behaves and then go to test do a pull for final tests?

My question is how does this work in practice with git flow and branches and developers and the repos on  different environments(production,test,dev).What is the work flow(working procedure)?

I am sorry for my long question.

Thank you.